# Emacs desktop-save-mode error

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'm not clear if this should be here or in superuser, but here goes.

I'm trying to use the [Desk Top](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop) package with latest Emacs. I've added (desktop-save-mode 1) to my .emacs but when starting emacs I am now getting the following error.

```
Error (frameset): Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil
```

I'm a bit of a loss at where to start debugging this and Google is being unhelpful.

Any ideas?

Stack trace added as requested

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
   2   +(nil 80 -1)
   3   frameset-move-onscreen(#<frame F1 0xb53310> t)
   4   frameset--restore-frame(((tty-type . "xterm-256color") (tty . "/dev/tty") (display-type . color) (background-mode . dark) (foreground-color . "#808080") (cursor-color . "#808080") (background-col$
   5   #[0 "\307\306@\236A\211A^A@\205^M^@\211\310\302!\203^[^@\302\306@\305\"\202^\^@\302\311\211\312^C!\203*^@\311^V \202J^@\313\311\314\"\314\306@\236A=\203=^@\311^V \202J^@\314\313\311\314\"B\211^V $
   6   funcall(#[0 "\307\306@\236A\211A^A@\205^M^@\211\310\302!\203^[^@\302\306@\305\"\202^\^@\302\311\211\312^C!\203*^@\311^V \202J^@\313\311\314\"\314\306@\236A=\203=^@\311^V \202J^@\314\313\311\314\"$
   7   frameset-restore([frameset 1 (21031 10481 847348 292000) (desktop . "206") "shomer@rubydev" nil nil ((((tty-type . "xterm-256color") (tty . "/dev/tty") (display-type . color) (background-mode . d$
   8   (progn (frameset-restore desktop-saved-frameset :reuse-frames desktop-restore-reuses-frames :force-display desktop-restore-in-current-display :force-onscreen desktop-restore-forces-onscreen))
   9   (if (desktop-restoring-frameset-p) (progn (frameset-restore desktop-saved-frameset :reuse-frames desktop-restore-reuses-frames :force-display desktop-restore-in-current-display :force-onscreen de$
  10   desktop-restore-frameset()
  11   (if (and owner (memq desktop-load-locked-desktop (quote (nil ask))) (or (null desktop-load-locked-desktop) (daemonp) (not (y-or-n-p (format "Warning: desktop file appears to be in use by PID %s.\$
  12   (let ((desktop-first-buffer nil) (desktop-buffer-ok-count 0) (desktop-buffer-fail-count 0) (owner (desktop-owner)) (desktop-save nil)) (if (and owner (memq desktop-load-locked-desktop (quote (nil$
  13   (if (file-exists-p (desktop-full-file-name)) (let ((desktop-first-buffer nil) (desktop-buffer-ok-count 0) (desktop-buffer-fail-count 0) (owner (desktop-owner)) (desktop-save nil)) (if (and owner $
  14   (if noninteractive nil (setq desktop-dirname (file-name-as-directory (expand-file-name (or (and (< 0 (length dirname)) dirname) (let ((dirs desktop-path)) (while (and dirs ...) (setq dirs ...)) ($
  15   desktop-read()
  16   (progn (desktop-read) (desktop-auto-save-set-timer) (setq inhibit-startup-screen t))
  17   (if desktop-save-mode (progn (desktop-read) (desktop-auto-save-set-timer) (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)))
  18   (closure (auto-insert desktop-buffer-locals desktop-buffer-major-mode desktop-buffer-fail-count desktop-buffer-ok-count desktop-first-buffer t) nil (let ((key "--no-desktop")) (if (member key com$
  19   run-hooks(after-init-hook)
  20   command-line()
  21   normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Try
`echo "(desktop-save-mode 1)" > test.el && emacs -q -l test.el`

Comment: Or `emacs -q --eval "(desktop-save-mode 1)"`

Comment: Hmm odd - no error message when I do that, but if I clear out .emacs to just include (desktop-save-mode 1) I still get the error...

Comment: Try deleting the old desktop file and let it create a new one the next time Emacs opens to eliminate that as a possible problem.  The default is to restore frames, so it is possible you have a frame something or other somewhere else in your setup file that is causing a conflict.  To turn off restore frames to help track down the root cause, try adding:  `(setq desktop-restore-frames nil)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same problem. I managed to fix it by setting

```
(setq desktop-restore-frames t)
(setq desktop-restore-in-current-display t)
(setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)
```

in my init.el

Comment: It is the `(setq desktop-restore-forces-onscreen nil)` line specifically that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Set `debug-on-error` to `t` in your init file. Rename or remove the byte-compiled file `desktop.elc`, so the source file, `desktop.el` is loaded -- that will give you a better debug backtrace.

When the error is raised a backtrace will be shown in the debugger (buffer `*Backtrace*`). That will give more info about what is causing the error, which in this case is the fact that `frameset` is expecting a number or marker and received `nil` instead.

Also, be sure you have updated Emacs, if you are using a development snapshot, because the `frameset.el` code is still being developed (it is brand new).  You can show your backtrace here.  It might be that there is a bug in `frameset.el` that needs to be reported.  If so, `M-x report-emacs-bug` is the way to do that. But try to investigate a bit first.

---

AFTER YOUR BACKTRACE ---

Please report this as a bug via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  This code in `frameset-move-onscreen` is the problem:

```
 (pcase-let* ((`(,left ,top ,width ,height) (cl-cdadr (frame-monitor-attributes frame)))
              (right (+ left width -1))
               ...
```

In your case (and it is not atypical), `(frame-monitor-attributes frame)` returns a list whose first element is `nil`, and that is bound to `left`.  The next binding tries to bind `right` to `(+ nil ...)`, which raises the error.  The `frameset.el` code is not robust enough to deal with a `nil` value for the `left` value returned by `frame-monitor-onscreen` (or else `frame-monitor-onscreen` should itself not return `nil` as the first list element).  Emacs Dev will be happy to get your bug report.

Comment: Thanks - I've added the backtrace to the question above. I've been having this issue for a few weeks and have been regularly updating git to see if it was a dev issue but no change so far.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I must confess I don't know Emacs well. I must also confess I don't know LISP at all. As a result the solution I found to this problem for my own personal use may be both extremely ignorant and is very likely to produce unpredictable results.

I am using the urxvt terminal and this appears to be the source of the problem. The GUI version of Emacs did not cause me any issues in this regard.

Effectively I used the above answer to identify the problem area. I then commented out the following line (1005) in frameset.el.gz:

```
(frameset-move-onscreen frame force-onscreen)
```

The I byte-compiled the file in Emacs. It now works to my entire satisfaction and I have yet to experience the (inevitable) side-effects.

The only reason I felt it was reasonable to try this (apart from despair) was that the goal this particular function was trying to achieve didn't seem too relevant to my system.